In keyd I am trying to implement this `menu = overload(rightmeta,menu)`. But It's not working
In keyd I am trying to implement this menu = overload(rightmeta,menu). But It's not working. I searched the output of keyd list-keys but couldn't find any key named super or leftsuper. But I did find keys named leftmeta and rightmeta and since the man page of keys writes those two modifiers using oblique sign, I tried to implement menu as rightmeta modifier key but it didn't work. So to figure out the problem I tested menu as control. It didn't work either. Then I tested dot as rightmeta key. That didn't work either. But I was successful to use dot as control key. These menu and super or leftmeta rightmeta are the only two things that I faced problems with. I didn't see anything in the mana page of keyd and neither in the github page. What's wrong with using some key as Super_R key. And what's wrong with menu key also.
Edit: Just a side question, in the output of keyd list-keys what the two keys named mouse1 and mouse2. I am not sure what they are acting for, but they are not acting for scroll up/down. And I couldn't see any scroll up/down keys.
I do realize that my question has become something like a venting letter that lists the things that I couldn't do with keyd, but I am happy with this application. It gives anyone super-powers.
